# SQL server - estimate execution time and get progress of alter table command

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

I have a very big table and from time to time I need to change its schema, add new columns, or change type of existing column for example.

This takes a lot of time (hours), and I wonder if there's any way to know beforehand how much time (approximately) it will take, or alternatively, when the alter is running, I'd like to know its current progress (i.e. 30% done).

Is this possible?

Comment: Not that I know of, no

Comment: Can't you alternatively create a new table with your desired structure and then copy the contents?

Comment: Nothing built in - you could maintain a copy of this table that just stores a small, representative sample of the data (e.g. 10000 rows) and make changes to that table first to assess the impact.

Comment: keep a record of historically how long your operations took, to give you a 'per record' speed. use this as a guide, but since there are so many variables affecting speed, you will not be able to know beforehand

Comment: Thanks all. I'm aware of those workaround, I was just wondering if there is something built in. I find it weird that there isn't...

Answer (score 0):

No - no such feature exists.

I'll just echo the workarounds suggested by commenters @Kermit and @Damien_The_Unbeliever here that you should create a new table with the desired schema, and move rows to it in batches (using a cursor). This approach allows you to `PRINT` feedback on progress, and is friendlier to your transaction log size to boot.